# Surge handling by Cloud Functions with Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am planning to use firebase with cloud functions for a use case where the load on the system can go from 0 to 50k-100k concurrent Users in the same instant. It is because there is a planned event on the system which begins at a planned time, and all the users will log in to the system at the same time. After that they will keep using the system for 1 to 2 hours and then again the load will drop to almost 0.  These users will read/write to realtime database directly and also call cloud functions. Regarding real time database, I think scaling should not be an issue. But I am not sure about the cloud functions.

1. Can firebase cloud functions handle such a surge
2. Is there any provisioning I need to do for this load
3. As I understand the cloud function will be provisioned more resources as more requests come in. Want to understand how much delay the users will experience when there is a surge from almost 0 to 100k users. Are there any chances for failed requests.
4. Is there a maximum number of user surge it can handle in such a scenario.
5. Any other suggestions.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a conversation rather than asking a discrete programming question.  I suggest you post to firebase-talk to start a conversation with the Firebase staff rather than using Stack Overflow. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/

Comment: I have posted the question on the google group. But I am getting replies from non firebasers who are also clueless on this. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/LCAFK1Epoe4

Comment: Kato Richardson is a Firebaser.  He knows what he's talking about.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

1) Can firebase handle such a surge

- Yes,firebase can handle such a surge.I read in an article in 2015 released by Google that 1 million users is the limit of users using firebase at a single shot was the limit by they have practically fixed this to unlimited users in 2015 according to their new update release.So handling such a surge would not be any issue.From my experience around 20k users at a time was not an issue.(have not tried more than that)

2) Is there any provisioning I need to do for this load.
i don't think so.

3) What will be the initial delay after the first request comes in for firebase to scale to this load, or, what will the maximum delay a user will face.

- For around 20k users there was approx 0 delay.I don'nt think you will face any issue of major delay.

4) Is there maximum number of users it can handle in such a scenario.

*No google has changed no of max users from 1 million to unlimited so no.

5) Any other suggestions.

*Again it all will depend on exactly what is your event..the data you would be using etc.But I would recommend you to contact firebase support first. https://firebase.google.com/support/
 The Flame and Blaze plans have a limit of 100,000 simultaneous connections per database above that you need to contact them.

Comment: thanks for the answer. For 20k users use case, have you used only realtime database or cloud functions also. I am asking because firebase reduces the resources allocated to cloud functions when they are not used, and allocates resources as they are used. So if you hit a cloud function after some time of inactivity then it takes more time to respond.

Comment: I used realtime database..monitoring temp and humidity in the datacenter was exactly my usecase and 20k users/devices were used.

Comment: Real time database, they have a common infrastructure to handle all requests. For cloud functions they allocate resources based on need.  So scaling will be different for both. This is my understanding.

Comment: Yeah..I just shared my experience..I strongly recommend you to contact firebase first coz they will clear all your doubts.Cheers